# How to prevent blurring on autocomplete selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am coding this asset tracker that displays assets in a table. When an asset is checked out, an input field is populated in one of the columns to indicate who authorized the asset checkout. This input box is bound to an auto complete list. When the input field loses focus the value in the box should become the text value of that cell which is then submitted to a database. The problem is when a selection is clicked on in the auto complete list, it accepts what the user has typed in rather than filling in the selection. How can I prevent this from occurring?

```
    $(".checkOut").live('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this),
        $currentRow = $this.closest("tr");
        $currentRow
            .removeClass("checkedIn")
            .addClass("checkedOut");
        $this.replaceWith('<button title="Check In" class="checkIn" value="true" name="check_in"><img alt="Check In" src="../images/check.png"></button>');
        $status = "1";
        $timestamp = $.ajax({
            url: "time.php",
            async: false
        }).responseText;
        $assetname = $currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").html();       
        $currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").html($who);
        $currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").html($when);
        $currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").html('<input type="text" id="auth" name="auth" value="" />');
        $auth = $currentRow.find("input");
        $auth.autocomplete("people.php").blur(function(event, ui) {
            if(!$auth.val()) {
                alert("Someone has to authorized this check out!");
                $auth.focus();
            }
            else {
                //accept input
                $authby = $auth.val();
                $currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text($authby);
                //submit data
                submitData($who,$when,$authby,$status,$assetname);
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are getting the value of the textbox i.e 
$authby = $auth.val();

What you need to do is, get the selected item
$authby = ui.item.value;

Comment: Also when you submit the data, why don't you just reuse the variable $authby instead of doing a  $auth.val() ? submitData($who,$when,$auth.val(),$status,$assetname);